# Viewing netlist on native ltspice for mac

Tags: ltspice, mac

I have a mac os x 10.9.3 and I run the native ltspice on it.  I cannot seem to access the netlist (the text file version of the schematic) on it.  Looking at the website: http://www.experimentalistsanonymous.com/ve3wwg/doku.php?id=ltspice_dirty_secrets#the_netlist

This website gives instuctions to "select menu “View” and then select “SPICE Netlist”" to view the netlist of the schematic.  However, as can be seen in the below screenshot, I have no option for "View" since it seems that the LTspice mac version has been pared down.  Any advice on how to remedy this would be awesome.  Thanks!
[image]

**Edit**
As @placeholder points out, I could just open it with a text editor.  (See text below)

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 304 208 224 208
WIRE 640 208 384 208
WIRE 224 288 224 208
WIRE 640 336 640 288
WIRE 224 416 224 368
WIRE 416 416 224 416
WIRE 640 416 416 416
WIRE 416 480 416 416
FLAG 416 480 0
SYMBOL voltage 224 272 R0
WINDOW 3 -285 248 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PWL file=/Users/eriktafari/Desktop/SPICE/Zebra_circuit/Zebra_voltage.txt
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL res 400 192 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Zebra_Resistance
SYMATTR Value 1.9
SYMBOL ind 624 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName Zebra_Inductance
SYMATTR Value 69.0E-9
SYMBOL ind 624 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName Load_Inductance
SYMATTR Value 5.0E-9
TEXT 24 200 Left 2 !.tran 0 500NS 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPICE netlists are just text files, so open in any editor that you have available.  I suggest BBEdit, or Nano on the command list or even preview.

Comment: Thanks @placeholder, that was a little bit obvious now that I see the answer.  I never had seen the text netlist from a schematic before (ie the SYMATTR Value xxx etc.) and had expected more of a traditional format.

Comment: I hope the Irony isn't lost on you - i.e. "traditional format"

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the schematic to drop down a menu which includes the View Menu.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user myself but don't they have a single mouse button, are you sure this is possible on the Mac version?

Comment: Older macs had the single click function although modern mice have the right-click capability
http://www.wikihow.com/Right-Click-on-a-Mac

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, but this was very helpful for me.